# Python creating your own library with resources

Tags: python

Hi all i'm trying to create my own python lib. I have a few resource files that I want to add to the library. I tried solving this by using:

> pkg_resources

in my setup.py I have:

```
packages=find_packages(),
package_data={"resources": ["extension.crx"]}
```

In my library code I try to use it like this:

```
filepath = pkg_resources.resource_filename('resources', 'extension.crx')
```

but using this filepath variable I get the following error:

```
OSError: Path to the resources doesn't exist
```

I install my library via

```
pip --use-feature=in-tree-build install ~/my_own_lib/
```

and I checked

```
~/python-venv/my_own_lib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/resources/extension.crx
```

However, the directory resources is empty. But the file I need
exists in the project directory for the library.

```
~/my_own_lib/resources/extension.crx
```

What am I missing here?

I'm running the code that uses the library with PyTest, not sure if that matters but I thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i missed

> include_package_data=True

in my setup.py